# How to encrypt a file non-interactively (using a stored private key)

Tags: encryption

I do not want to run something like `gpg -c` as it prompts me for a passphrase. I will have  cron job that backs-up and encypts some files. I want to pass in a location to a private key (via arguements) to an application that can encrypt a stream (ie: instead of encrypting just a file, it can use the pipe character, `|`, as input).

Symmetric encryption like AES or the like is preferred.

One more thing, I want it to be a private key that I store somewhere on the file system. Not a private key that is managed by a key server or some kind of application specific key container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use `gpg -c --passphrase-file=...` or `gpg -c --passphrase-fd=...`. For example:

```
dmesg | gpg -c --passphrase-fd=3 --batch > dmesg.txt.gpg 3< zombies.key
```

To decrypt:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase-fd=3 3< zombies.key --output decrypted.txt --decrypt dmesg.txt.gpg
```

(I think `gpg` does default to CAST, though, so also add `--cipher-algo AES256`.)

Alternatively, `openssl cipher -aes256`.